# What things determine the sequence of Bean. who will first loaded in container and which bean object crearte at first

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

A,B C, And when i am using setter injection for All , And one bean reference to each other. then what will be sequence of bean for object creation.
And when i am using constructor injection for all and A have B reference B have c reference and c have a reference then what will be the sequence for object creation?.

Comment: What happens when you try it? Put a System.out.println("in A") in the constructor of A (and same for B and C), and see by yourself.

Comment: I want some logical way for answer Behalf of that it will give proper output.